# Acess to WebService from Hololens

Tags: web-services, hololens

I'm trying to access a webservice from the Hololens but I have a "Cannot connect to destination host" error. The Webservice is not the problem, when I open Edge within the Hololens and type my WS url I have the desired result. However when I try with "google.com" it works. I must have forgotten to enable something in my manifest but I do not know what. I have check both "Internet Client" and "InternetClientServer".

I am targeting IL2CPP scripting backend but it works with .NET.

Here's the code I use to acces to my Web Service :

```
public static IEnumerator GetUrl(string url, Action<string> callback)
    {            
        UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(WWW.EscapeURL(url));

        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        if(request.isDone)
        {
            if (request.isNetworkError )
            {
                Debug.Log("network error: "+request.error);
                callback(request.error);
            }else if (request.isHttpError)
            {
                Debug.Log("http error: " + request.error);
                callback(request.error);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("OK: " + request.downloadHandler.text);
                callback(request.downloadHandler.text);
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the call to that method :

```
StartCoroutine(
        ApiManager.GetUrl(
            "10.2.68.93:3000/hello",
            result => resultTextMesh.text = result
        )
    );
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: After different configurations tried, I discovered that the version 2017.3.1f1 doesn't allow the Hololens to receive the answer from the WebService. I'm now running the app on Unity 2017.2.1f1 (64-bit) and it works perfectly. Can't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [WWW](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) object which seems to work better.

Comment: Didn't work. WWW is just a simplification of what UnityWebRequest does

Comment: Do you have the same result if you add the "http://" in the URL? In Unity do you have the same problem if you run on it?

Comment: It doesn't work either with the "http://". When I run the app on unity it actually works but can't connect as soon as I use the app on the Hololens. I guess it's about authorizations but I already enabled the internet capabilities "internetClient" and "internetClientServer"

Comment: You said, it is not working on HoloLens - is it on device or emulator ? If it's device, do you have wifi / network setup over there .  Just could be a possibility...

Comment: On device - it works on the emulator - and yes the Wi-fi is enabled and working (edge works).